# WPF baml serialization bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, baml

The following XAML produces `XamlParseException` in runtime:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary>
            <TextBlock x:Key="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Run Text="Aaaa"/>
            </TextBlock>
          </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <sys:String x:Key="aaa"></sys:String>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Border Child="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

> XamlParseException: 'Missing key value on 'TextBlock' object.' Line number '10' and line position '20'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using XamlReader.Parse? If so, does it work in XamlPadX? If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6850713/21475) may be related.

Comment: I'm just running app with XAML above as main window :)

Answer (score -1):

Keys can't be types, they're strings.

Comment: Please, learn some WPF before answering such questions :)))))

Comment: So learned, my apologies. Tho I think setting TargetType would be more readable.